# How to show that this function gets every real value exactly once?

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = {e^{\frac{1}{x}}} - \ln x$$

I thought maybe to use the Intermediate value theorem.
Thought to create 2 functions from this one. and subtracting.
And finally I will get something in the form of

$$f(c) - c = 0$$
$$f(c) = c$$

But how I proof that this function gets every real value but only once ?
So it must be monotonic.
What theorem should I use here ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x) = {e^{\frac{1}{x}}} - \ln(x)$$ Its derivative is $$f'(x)=-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}$$ is always negative since $x>0$ (because of the logarithm); so the function always decreases. It also starts at $+\infty$ when $x\to 0$ and goes to $-\infty$ when $x\to \infty$.

You could also show that $f''(x)>0$ for any $x$.

I suppose that this is sufficient to show that you can find a single $x$ such that $f(x)=k$ for any positive or negative value of $k$.

Comment: well this explains surjectivity, but not really injectivity (for the *exactly once* in OP). Although you prove that the function is *strictly decreasing* which implies injectivity.

Comment: You are more than probably right ! May I confess that I have problems with  *surjectivity,  injectivity* (as well as with many other things) ? I am not a mathematician in the proper sense of the term.

Answer (score 1):

$$a>b \iff \frac{1}{a} < \frac{1}{b} \iff e^{1/a} < e^{1/b} \iff e^{1/b} - e^{1/a} > 0 \iff e^{1/b} - \ln b >  e^{1/a} - \ln b$$

But $$e^{1/a} - \ln b > e^{1/a} - \ln a$$

We have the function $f(x) = \displaystyle e^{\frac{1}{x}} - \ln x$ and derivative $$f'(x)=-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}$$ The derivative is always negative, since we require that $x>0$ for the function to be defined (logarithm). Note also that $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \infty$$ whilst $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = -\infty$$

Now that we've proven that the function achieves every real value (surjective) we need to prove that the function achieves every real value **exactly once** which is the injective property of the function. This can be done by showing that $f(a) < f(b)$ is equivalent to $a < b$.

$$\begin{align}a<b &\iff \frac{1}{a} > \frac{1}{b} \\ &\iff e^{1/a} > e^{1/b} \\ &\iff e^{1/a} - e^{1/b} > 0 \\ &\iff e^{1/a} - \ln a >  e^{1/b} - \ln a\end{align}$$

But we know that if $a<b$ then $\ln a < \ln b$ and hence $e^{1/b} - \ln a > e^{1/b} - \ln b$ so that we get $$a<b \iff e^{1/a} - \ln a > e^{1/b} - \ln a > e^{1/b} - \ln b \iff f(b) > f(a) \iff f(a) < f(b)$$

And so, since we've just shown that $$a<b \iff f(a) < f(b)$$ our function is strictly decreasing and hence injective. Proving that it achieves ever real value exactly once.

A quick sketch of the graph verifies our result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the derivative to show that the function is monotonic

the derivative is

$ \frac{-1}{x^2} e ^{\frac{1}{x}} - \frac{1}{x} < 0$

so the function is monotonic

when x tends to 0 the function tends to ${\infty}$
and when x tends to ${\infty}$ the function tends to $-{\infty}$
so the function will get every real value exactly once

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** set $z=\frac{1}{x}$.

Then $f(x) = e^{z}+\log z = g(z)$ is a continuous increasing function, since it is the sum of two continuous increasing functions. Moreover: $$\lim_{z\to 0^+}g(z)=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{z\to +\infty} g(z) = +\infty. $$